# TextArea fit to a GridPane

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, gridpane

I´m new to Java.

I want to fit a `TextArea` in a `GridPane`. I tried this for the last few hours with this result:

[image]

As you see, the `TextArea` is much bigger than my `Gridpane`. Here is my code:

```
GridPane root = new GridPane();
root.setGridLinesVisible(true);
root.setHgap(20);
root.setVgap(8);
root.setPadding(new Insets( 10, 10, 10, 10));

ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints();
col1.setPercentWidth(50);
ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
col2.setPercentWidth(50);
root.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2);

RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
RowConstraints row2 = new RowConstraints();
RowConstraints row3 = new RowConstraints();
RowConstraints row4 = new RowConstraints();


row1.setPrefHeight(20);
row2.setPrefHeight(20);
row3.setPrefHeight(40);
row4.setPrefHeight(20);

root.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1,row2,row3,row4);

GridPane.setVgrow(root, Priority.ALWAYS);


Label Opt1 = new Label("Operand 1");
Label Opt2 = new Label("Operand 2");
Label Erg = new Label("Ergebnis");


TextArea txtOpt1 = new TextArea();
TextArea txtOpt2 = new TextArea();
TextArea txtErg = new TextArea();


txtErg.setEditable(false);

Button btnPlus = new Button("+");
Button btnMinus = new Button("-");
Button btnMal = new Button("*");
Button btnGeteilt = new Button("/");

HBox Opts = new HBox(10);
HBox hblbl1 = new HBox();

hblbl1.getChildren().add(txtOpt1);

Opts.getChildren().add(btnGeteilt);
Opts.getChildren().add(btnMal);
Opts.getChildren().add(btnMinus);
Opts.getChildren().add(btnPlus);
Opts.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

root.add(Opt1, 0, 0);
root.add(Opt2, 0, 1);
root.add(hblbl1, 1, 0);
root.add(txtOpt2, 1, 1);
root.add(Opts, 0, 2, 2, 1);
root.add(Erg, 0, 3);
root.add(txtErg, 1, 3);
```

Comment: Did you try grid.add(textArea)?

Comment: See [mcve], your code is not runnable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the TextArea is much bigger than my Gridpane

Because you are restricting the rows of the grid pane to a height which is smaller than what the text area can fit in.

It looks like what you are looking for is actually `TextField`, not `TextArea`. I would remove the constraints on the rows and use `TextFields` instead:

[image]

Also, `GridPane.setVgrow(root, Priority.ALWAYS);` does nothing. `setVgrow` specifies which component *within* the grid pane should grow and how. If you specify the grid pane itself as the component it's meaningless.